# Laravel collection map use private function in same class instead closure

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection, php-closures

I use the map function to loop each object of collections.
The closure method is too long and I tried to make it a private function.
But I cannot successfully call the function.

Here is my sample code. (note: the function test may be very long in real case)

```
<?php

class cls
{
    private function test($a) {
        return ($a + 1);
    }

    public function run1() {
        return ($this->test(5));
    }

    public function run2() {
        $col = Collect([1,2,3]);
        return ($col->map($this->test()));
    }

    public function run3() {
        $col = Collect([1,2,3]);
        $mycls = $this;
        return ($col->map(function ($c) use ($mycls) {
            return($mycls->test($c));
        }));
    }
}

$c = new cls;
$c->run1(); # 6
$c->run2(); # Error: Too Few Argements
$c->run3(); # [2,3,4]
```

I use the function: run1 to test if the private function is callable and I failed at function: run2.
Although function: run3 makes code shorten. It seems a little bit too superfluous.
How can I make run2 works?

### Update

My version of Laravel is 6.2

### Update

I tried the @xenooooo answer.
It works with the public function, but I get a different error code with the private method.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer:** `$this->test()` required a parameter and you are simply not passing anything to it.

You can also modify your **run2/run3** methods to do the following:

```
public function run2() {
   $col = collect([1,2,3])->map(function ($value) {
      return $this->test($value);
   });
        
   return $col; //returns a collection of items
   //return $col->toArray(); //(extra option) returns an array of collected items
}
```

**Result:**

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#872 ▼ 
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => 2
    1 => 3
    2 => 4
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

You may read more on collections here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#introduction

Comment: You are right. I can just use `$this` inside my closure, which I think it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `run2` is that you are calling the method directly and you need to pass the an argument since `test` is expecting argument `$a`. To use the method as a callback function you need the pass it as an array which is the first value is `$this` and the second is the method name which is `test` :

```
public function test($a) {
    return ($a + 1);
}

public function run2()
{
    $collection = collect([1,2,3]);

    $newCollection = $collection->map([$this,'test']);

    return $newCollection;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It only work if the method that you will call is public and it will not work if you use a private or protected method. If you use a private or protected if will throw a `BadMethodCallException`

Comment: How is your answer different than the above answer? Don't just copy others answers.

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Support\Collection::map() must be callable, array given

Comment: I think array_map is work but collection map is not work

Comment: I don't know where is the `copy` that you talking about ?

Comment: Also I don't know why there is an error for you but mine is working.

Comment: I don't know the copy thing either.

Comment: @xenooooo It works with the public method, but I get TypeError in the private method instead of BadMethodCallException. I'll update the screenshot in my question.